# Diagonal disorder in SQL query in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem when doing a SQL query in WordPress, I would like to have each Post ID in a single row with the meta_key columns, but I get several uneven records.

```
SELECT P.ID,
     IF(PM.meta_key = 'nombrem', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS nombrem,
     IF(PM.meta_key = 'generom', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS generom,
     IF(PM.meta_key = 'tiempom', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS tiempom,
     IF(PM.meta_key = 'urlm', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS urlm,
     IF(PM.meta_key = 'imagenm', PM.meta_value, NULL) AS imagenm 
FROM K1nG_posts AS P
LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON ( P.ID = PM.post_id ) 
WHERE P.post_type = 'post' 
AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

By placing the above code I get the following in phpmyadmin, I want a single post ID to have each meta_value value in a non-diagonal horizontal column as shown.

[image]

Comment: What is an "urgent character"?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You seeem to be looking for *conditional aggregation*. For this, you would need to add a `GROUP BY` clause and surround your conditional expressions with an aggregate function:

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'nombrem' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS nombrem,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'generom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS generom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'tiempom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS tiempom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'urlm'    THEN PM.meta_value END) AS urlm,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'imagenm' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS imagenm
FROM 
    K1nG_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON P.ID = PM.post_id 
WHERE 
    P.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')  
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date
ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the data by P.id and max the ifs out

like

```
SELECT P.ID,
 MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'nombrem', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS nombrem,
 MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'generom', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS generom,
 MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'tiempom', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS tiempom,
 MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'urlm', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS urlm,
 MAX(IF(PM.meta_key = 'imagenm', PM.meta_value, NULL)) AS imagenm 
FROM K1nG_posts AS P
  LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON ( P.ID = PM.post_id ) 
WHERE P.post_type = 'post' 
  AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY P.post_date DESC
GROUP BY P.ID;
```